# The right word to indicate someone that reacts to something

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

My first question here, let me know if I am missing some details.

Basically, I need to find the right word to represent a specific entity.

How can I call someone who reacts to something? Not necessarily in an impulsive way. Just reacting to something.

At first, I thought something about "reagent" but I discovered it's a technical (chemistry) word.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. [Single word requests](/tags/single-word-requests/info) **must include a sample sentence** demonstrating how the word would be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the word *responder*, derived from the verb *to respond*:

> to do something as a reaction to something that has happened or been done

<sub>source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/responder)</sub>